# The use of "black box" as a synonym of "mysterious"

Tags: word-usage, writing-style

> Full details are provided so that the method is less mysterious.

I would like to replace "less mysterious". 
Is the following proposal valid for (scientific) writing?

> Full details are provided so that the method is less like a "black box".

Comment: How about "full details are provided for transparency". Because a black box is anything but transparent.

Comment: I think there's something of a "register mismatch" here. *Full details are provided...* sounds like a formal usage, but *being a "black box"* (not ***like** a black box*) is informal "geek speak" for *not exposing the internal workings*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is less appropriate than you think.

The "[Black Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box)" term has a number of meanings.  In engineering, it means an operation that acts as part of the mechanism without any clear indication of how it is working.  But in aviation, it represents a box that captures a voice recording of the pilot to reveal what has happened in the plane after an accident, and is anything but a cause for mystery.  Though there are many ways in which "black box" is used to mean a mysterious thing, it is vague enough that it could be confusing to a reader.

More to the point, you're trying to use a negation to represent a quality, which is usually a bad idea to begin with.  It would be much better to indicate that the method is "easier to understand", "clearly defined", "readable", or any other word that means the actual quality you are trying to describe.

It is also far better to use concrete terms to describe the quality, rather than using a metaphorical object, so that you can fully describe what you are trying to say, rather than forcing the reader to guess at what quality you are hinting at.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I'll go for "more transparent", as suggested by @LindaBrammer in her comment.